# How to create mllib.linalg.Matrix from an text file

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

I know that I can create Matrix like this:

```
val values = Array(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
val mat = Matrices.dense(m, n, values).asInstanceOf[DenseMatrix]
```

But now I have a text file and it is a matrix like this:

```
0.0 1.0

2.0  3.0

4.0  5.0
```

I want to know how to create Matrix from this file.

Can I do this:

```
val test3=sc.textFile("textFile").map(_.split("\t").map(_.toDouble)).asInstanceOf[DenseMatrix]
```

But it seems doesn't work

anyone help me?

Comment: Matrix reads the data Array by column, so you will need to change your data input to [0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0] for it to work. You might need to do some mapping of your text file first

Answer (score 2):

The `Matrices.dense` method takes a column major list of values.  If you have data in a text file, it is row-major. So, doing the following:

```
val dValues = sc.textFile("textFile").flatMap(_.split("\t").map(_.toDouble))
val matrix = Matrices.dense(rows, columns, dValues)
```

gives you the wrong kind of matrix.  But, there is a simple fix:

```
val matrix = Matrices.dense(columns, rows, dValues).transpose
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have skipped an step.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Matrix, Matrices}

val dValues = sc.textFile("textFile").map(_.split("\t").map(_.toDouble))
val matrix = Matrices.dense(3, 2, dValues)
```

You can remove the `.asInstanceOf[DenseMatrix]`. It is not necessary.